# How to fix a Firebase Cloud Functions Bad Request in React-Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm fairly new to Firebase cloud functions and I've been trying to integrate Stripe into my RN project using FB but keep getting a bad request response. I'll see a few things when I try to run this:

1. Request is missing body.
2. Invalid request, unable to process.
3. Bad Request (400).

Does anyone know where I should go from here?

In my index.js file:

```
exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onCall(async (data, response) => {

try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        data: {
            amount: 100,
            currency: "usd",
            payment_method_types: ["card"]
        }
    });

    const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret;

    response.json({
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    response.json({ error: e.message });
}
```

})

On the app side:

```
const fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${FUNCTION_URL}/create-payment-intent`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });

    const { clientSecret, error } = await response.json();
    return { clientSecret, error };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cloud Function is a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), as we can see from the code: `functions.https.onCall()`. As explained in the doc "HTTPS callable functions are similar but not identical to [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)"

You should call it from your app by using the specific methods of the JS SDK, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).

It is possible to call it via fetch (or any other library used to make `XMLHttpRequests` from the browser) but then you need to follow the [Protocol specification for `https.onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) which is not straightforward. So it is highly recommended to use the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In your cloud function , You use HTTP callable function which is not the same as HTTP function. You can read more from
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd

You should call HTTP callable function with client SDK httpsCallable() in your client